# Recover Directory imediatly after failed 'nnn' (filebrowser) renaming

Tags: data-recovery, nnn

After building a local data-server with a bunch of older hard drives on one HDD I've observed that I had switched the naming of two directories. With the 'nnn' file-browser (with the 'r' keybinding, which calls the 'vi' editor in which you can rename all sub-directories at once) I renamed them how they should actually be -- switched the names.

However, after saving and exiting 'vi', one of the two directories has disappeared.

Without any changes, I immediatly exited the drive, unmounted it and suspended automatic mounting at startup.

The directory included backuped files wich are rather important. Ideally it would be nice if it would be possible to restore the **files including the names and the directory structure**.

What are the chances for restoration and how could I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The lost directory was moved as a subdirectory, having the same name, inside the first of the two. Nice!

Renamed it and moved it outside.

Comment: Next time just execute ordinary `mv` to save you from troubles. If you do not know particular software extremely well do not use it for managing critical information!